# Camera2 default control scene mode is CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Before setting any parameters to `CaptureRequest.Builder` I checked that default control scene mode is not disabled

```
Timber.d("captureRequestBuilder sceneMode ${get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE)} == ${CameraMetadata.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_DISABLED}")
Timber.d("captureRequestBuilder mode ${get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE)} == ${CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO}")
```

> captureRequestBuilder sceneMode 1 == 0
>
> captureRequestBuilder mode 1 == 1

`CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_DISABLED = 0;`

`CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY = 1;`

Why `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY` is default control scene mode for Camera2?

And what should I set instead if I use Camera2 for a dashboard camera app (video recorder for cars)? It's definitely should not be face recognition on the road...

I thought default scene would be disabled until developer set it explicitly...

All possible values (of course those scene modes may not be supported all by devices):

[image]

Comment: the scene mode is default to face as most uses are regarding this scenario. i you case for dashCam usage i would go with either scene setting disabled or using the hdr parameter

Comment: @AkashPal it seems `Disabled` means that there is no other scene modes: __If no scene modes are supported by the camera device, this will be set to DISABLED. Otherwise DISABLED will not be listed.__ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AVAILABLE_SCENE_MODES

Comment: so usually phones support only `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY` and may have `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most use cases, it's best to leave it to FACE_PRIORITY if the phone uses that as the default.

That mode allows the camera metering to make people's faces look as good as possible - it does not do face *recognition*, just face *detection*. So it finds where there are faces, and tries to make sure those areas are well-lit and focused on.

Bu if you want to, you can turn it off by just turning off scene mode entirely, by setting [CONTROL_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_MODE) to [AUTO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#CONTROL_MODE_AUTO) instead of [USE_SCENE_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#CONTROL_MODE_USE_SCENE_MODE).  When set to AUTO, the value of CONTROL_SCENE_MODE is ignored.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use `AUTO` control mode when `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY` is set as control scene mode and use `USE_SCENE_MODE` control mode for `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR` and `CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_NIGHT`